# Querying database with laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have below query in my controller, this works perfectly fine without using relationships model.

```
        $menuitems = Menuitems::select(['item_id','item_name','item_price', 'item_code', 'item_status', 'menu_group_name'])
                               ->join('menu_item_groups', 'menu_items.itemgroup_id', '=', 'menu_item_groups.menu_group_id')
                               ->get();
```

Now I tried to use relationships and I defined below relationship in **Menuitems** model is below, because each menu item belongs to one of **Menuitemgroup**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Menuitems extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'menu_items';
    protected $primaryKey = 'item_id';

    public function menuitemgroup()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Menuitemgroups::class, 'menu_group_id', 'itemgroup_id' );
    }
    
}
```

Now I want to run the same query as join, but I could not find a code which runs correctly, **menu_group_name** is part of another table **Menuitemgrous** which is id of **menu_group_id**

I am passing $menuitems to datatables as json.

How can I query **$menuitems**?

Comment: You need to define both sides of the relationship. Menuitems model also needs a hasMany defined

Answer (score 0):

Using Eloquent and Laravel relationships, you can try the below

```php
$menuitems = Menuitems::with('menuitemgroup')
  ->get()
  ->map(function($item){
      $value = $item->menuitemgroup->menu_group_name;
      unset($item->menuitemgroup);
    
      $item->menuitemgroup = $value;
    
      return $item;
            
  });
```

By the way you should also have inverse relationship defined on Menuitemgroup

```php
//App\Models\Menuitems.php
public function menuitemgroup()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Menuitemgroups::class, 'itemgroup_id', 'menu_group_id' );
}


//App\Models\Menuitemgroups.php
public function menuitems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Menuitems::class, 'itemgroup_id', 'menu_group_id');
}
```

Comment: I got this as error, message: "Call to undefined relationship [menuitemgroup] on model [App\Models\Menuitems]."

Comment: Check that you have the relationship defined on Menuitem class

Comment: Already defined in same class, but still same error. Even added in Menuitemgroup model as well.

Comment: Try the with('menuitemgroup') without filtering columns as updated in answer and if you added model class recently then also run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Same issue, no change in error, for whatsoever reason, it could not find relationship function

Comment: I think the foreignKey and ownerKey are misplaced in the menuitemgroup relation definition, interchange them - have updated ans

Comment: No, that is not an issue, it has been already tried.

Comment: Hi, I could now able to load relationship and getting all data of Menugroupitems, but i need only 1 column data to get populated in output, i tried with your earlier code, but it does not work to get menu_group_name field data. How can i get that column value?

Comment: You can specify it in the with `Menuitems::with('menuitemgroups:menu_group_id,menu_group_name')` assuming that **menu_group_id** is the linking column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225771/discussion-between-rjcode-and-donkarnash).

Comment: @rjcode Do you want menu_group_name as key and its value as value i.e menu_group_name: "Wows" instead of menuitemgroup: "Wows"?